# Is contrast necessary to existence?

Tags: metaphysics

e.g. For high to exist there must be low.
   .For fast to exist there must be slow.
   .For good to exist there must be bad.
      .For love to exist there must be hatred. [Love is expressed as it confronts that which it hates].

Is contrast necessary to existence?

Comment: Yes. See [Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus) : ["Pólemos pántōn mèn patḗr esti"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_phrases#%CE%A0%CF%80).

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA You say "yes" but does not existence precede the quality of existence?

Comment: To exist is to 'stand-out' from a contrasted background. As Schrodinger notes, as well as existents there is 'the canvas on which they are painted'. Existence requires contrast. Hence the mystics call the mundane world the 'world of opposites'. . .

Comment: For a toothpick to exist there must be... ? "Exist" is a strange word to use here since whatever is characterized as "high" or "fast" might just as well be called "low" and "slow" without changing one bit. Only its label changes depending on the scale chosen, and that has nothing to do with its existence. To the extent that the meaning of "contrast" is implied by your examples, it is necessary for labeling, not for existence. But really, you should be more specific and explicit, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Conifold If the toothpick was composed/conjunction of such properties we would call that a formalist view, and if there was more to a toothpick than being low, fast and bad, that is objectivist? But now from an objectivist perspective, does these "label" words not have any form of existence? Is there no objective reality to "fast" or "good"?

Comment: None, until a baseline is specified. Then it is a question of realism/nominalsim about universals as to how objective the comparative relation is. But that is moot where existence of entities like the toothpick are concerned.

Comment: Indeed not many are consistent existentialists and you can tell by the way they count how many existences there are...

Answer (score 1):

All of it is a matter of **point of view**.

When you see fast and slow for example, I only see different **degrees** of speed.

Human is really good at making **opposites** probably because it is **easier** for us. It is more like the human brain built all the contrasts to make it easier for us. **Fast/Slow**, **Good/Bad**, **High/Low** are **bounds** of our vision and there is many thing between you can't describe.

Also, nothing tells us that the notions you talk about **exists**. If these are **abstractions** we built, there is probably no fast and no slow, no good and no bad, no love and no hate. There are simply **notions** you can apply to situations.

For example, when you are on a highway at the right speed, you can't tell you're going **fast** or **slow**. It is just something **between** you can't describe. And maybe you can't describe them because you don't have a **definition** of them. And maybe you don't have definition (nobody have one) because these things don't **exist**.

Answer (score 1):

```
Existence:

(Meaning)

1.The fact or state of living or having objective reality.

2.Existence is the ability of an entity to interact with physical or mental reality.
```

For existence of an entity, contrast is necessary.

You gave a few words and their opposites to convince the necessity of contrast.  But before dealing this word--existence, we should think whether existence has an imaginable opposite. We may be using the word 'nonexistence' as its opposite.  But what is it?  Is it an abstract noun actually?

So, for existence there is no need of a contrast. But to know the existence of an entity, contrast is necessary.

For the existence of the Ultimate Truth, no contrast is necessary.  In other words, if there is Ultimate Truth it must be the absolute existence.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic question. Yes.

Without the essence of contrast (the difference between any two properties of physics) movement would not be able to occur, change would not be able to occur, "creation" would not be able to occur. Time itself can only exist if there are physical differences for it to take place.

One could say the essence of contrast created time itself.

Existence without change, essentially just stillness that doesn't move, may be possible without contrast. But anything other than this state requires the essence contrast in order to be.

One could say contrast is "divine".

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me: Existence is not dependent upon something else. Nothing  could act as a prior explanation of existence because any prior existence would have to exist. e.g. the contrast between non-existence and existence could not cause existence because to be a first cause it would have to exist. Therefore nothing is necessary to existence except itself. This appears to be something of the logic in "I am that I am."